# Parsing MySQL rows to JavaScript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, parsing, quotes

Hi guys can't seem to use MySQL row values in JavaScript. I've tried all kinds of quote and double-quote combinations.

```
$sql = "SELECT desk_id, desk_x, desk_y FROM desks";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'new Desk('$row["desk_id"]', '$row["desk_x"]', '$row["desk_y"]')';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
>   ',' or ';'

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** Thanks for the answers guys.

This works:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "new Desk('{$row["desk_id"]}', '{$row["desk_x"]}', '{$row["desk_y"]}')"; 
    echo '</script>';            
}
```

When I try to put the  open and close tags outside of the while loop I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

Comment: you need to escape the single quotes using ( \ )

Comment: `echo "new Desk('{$row["desk_id"]}', '{$row["desk_x"]}', '{$row["desk_y"]}')";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, that is neater than dot concatenation.

Comment: @TimothyGroote Yup all week long and twice on Sunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the need to escape characters ; In PHP, string concatenation is done with the `.` (period)

```
echo 'new Desk('.$row["desk_id"].', '.$row["desk_x"].', '.$row["desk_y"].')';
```

Or

```
echo "new Desk('{$row["desk_id"]}', '{$row["desk_x"]}', '{$row["desk_y"]}')";
```

Comment: Hope you dont mind?

Comment: Nah, of course not! It's neater than my original suggestion

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best way to deal with php and javascript.. It would be much better to do ajax call.

If you want to put php variable into string please try this way:

```
echo 'new Desk('.$row["desk_id"].', '.$row["desk_x"].', '.$row["desk_y"].')';
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** Move your script tag to outside the while loop

**2nd :** use `escape` character `(\)`  or use `double` quotes like this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "new Desk('{$row["desk_id"]}', '{$row["desk_x"]}', '{$row["desk_y"]}')";

    }
     echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Messing up javascript with PHP is discouraged. You could use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) calls.

As per your question, if you want to enquote the javascript input parameters, you have to escape them properly with backslash:

```
echo 'new Desk(\''.$row["desk_id"].'\', \''.$row["desk_x"].'\', \''.$row["desk_y"].'\')';
```

But if you are sure your parameters are numbers, you don't need to enquote them:

```
echo 'new Desk('.$row["desk_id"].', '.$row["desk_x"].', '.$row["desk_y"].')';
```